# My Android Studio may have some issue

Tags: android-studio, layout, widget

I am using Android Studio 2.3.3 . but it appears a little different from others. It look like:

[image]

But I want that it look like this:

[image]

Please suggest what to do?

Comment: FYI it's not an issue. It's a feature. The Android Studio version is RC 1.0 in the second screenshot which you have posted.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Look for the red circle. It has a settings icon, click on that and select the option, "Include Device Frame (If Available)" and you will have the black overlay around the device, which you want.

However for the Palette to look the way you want, you have to downgrade your Android Studio to at least '2.1.2'. Because for your version that is the way the palette will look.